# How to delete one kind of data from output CSV file created by BeautifuleSoup Python

Tags: python, selenium, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
<small class="truncate text-bold">Heart ...</small>
<small class="truncate text-bold">Fuse</small>
<small class="truncate text-bold">Fuse</small>
<small class="truncate text-bold">hello</small>
<small class="truncate text-bold">trap</small>
<small class="truncate text-bold">Fuse</small>
<small class="truncate text-bold">kick</small>
<small class="truncate text-bold">Fuse</small>

<small class="truncate text-bold blurple2">I 1</small>
<small class="truncate text-bold blurple2">I 2</small>
<small class="truncate text-bold blurple2">I 3</small>
<small class="truncate text-bold blurple2">I 4</small>
<small class="truncate text-bold blurple2">I 5</small>
<small class="truncate text-bold blurple2">I 6</small>
<small class="truncate text-bold blurple2">I 7</small>


for row in c_soup:
    s_c = row.find("small",{'class':'truncate text-bold'}).text.strip()
    s_i = row.find("small",{'class':'truncate text-bold blurple2'}).text.strip()
    

    print(s_i + ' ' + s_c)
```

My Output is

1. I 1 Heart ....
2. I 2 Fuse
3. I 3 Fuse
4. I 4 hello
5. I 5 trap
6. I 6 Fuse
7. I 7 kick
8. I 8 Fuse

I don't want fuse in my output

1. I 1 Heart ....
2. I 4 Hello
3. I 5 trap
4. I 7 kick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to "zip" texts from `<small>` tags, but not ones that contain the word "Fuse":

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = '''<small class="truncate text-bold">Heart ...</small>
<small class="truncate text-bold">Fuse</small>
<small class="truncate text-bold">Fuse</small>
<small class="truncate text-bold">hello</small>
<small class="truncate text-bold">trap</small>
<small class="truncate text-bold">Fuse</small>
<small class="truncate text-bold">kick</small>
<small class="truncate text-bold">Fuse</small>

<small class="truncate text-bold blurple2">I 1</small>
<small class="truncate text-bold blurple2">I 2</small>
<small class="truncate text-bold blurple2">I 3</small>
<small class="truncate text-bold blurple2">I 4</small>
<small class="truncate text-bold blurple2">I 5</small>
<small class="truncate text-bold blurple2">I 6</small>
<small class="truncate text-bold blurple2">I 7</small>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

for a, b in zip( soup.select('.truncate:not(.blurple2)'), soup.select('.blurple2') ):
    if 'Fuse' in a.text:
        continue
    print(b.text + ' ' + a.text)
```

Prints:

```
I 1 Heart ...
I 4 hello
I 5 trap
I 7 kick
```